# How to convert object to serialised object in react native?

Tags: react-native, serialization

I have an object similar to below

```
const params = {
      token: '78fe6df3f',
      id: '12345',
      price: 0 - '9,000,000',
      'area[]': 'Applehead Island',
      'waterfront_type[]': 'Open Water',
      property_type_single: 'Single Family/Site Built',
      bedrooms: '0 - 5',
      baths: '0 - 5',
      sqft: '0 - 7500'
    };
```

I want this object to be turned to like below `https://www.example.com/properties.php?token=78fe6df3f&id=12345&price=$0%20-%20$3,480,000&area[]=Applehead%20Island&waterfront_type[]=Open%20Water&property_type_single=Single%20Family/Site%20Built&bedrooms=0%20-%205&baths=0%20-%205&sqft=0%20-%207500`
How can I get this in react native. In javascript `$.param(obj)` does this job. Please guide me.

I want the above to do fetch calls in react native. The object will be generated by the filter form.

Comment: I am sure if you google for js url builder library you can find a lot of 3rd party dependencies which process object into query params.

Comment: [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/build-url) looks promising. You can pass the object as you described into this and it will be appended as url query params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const paramsToString = params => Object.entries(params).reduce((acc, [key, value], index, array) => `${acc}${key}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}${index !== (array.length - 1) ? '&' : ''}`, "");

const params = {
      token: '78fe6df3f',
      id: '12345',
      price: '0 - 9,000,000',
      'area[]': 'Applehead Island',
      'waterfront_type[]': 'Open Water',
      property_type_single: 'Single Family/Site Built',
      bedrooms: '0 - 5',
      baths: '0 - 5',
      sqft: '0 - 7500'
    };
    
console.log(paramsToString(params));
```

Comment: This is nice but an explanation should be nice.